# Form not being displayed in pop-up window #Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a jquery/javascript beginner. I have to accept a few details in a pop-up form (On clicking the "Add an employee" button). The form isnt being displayed in the pop-up. Infact the popup itself isnt coming. I know im going drastically wrong somewhere, can someone please help! I've been stuck on this issue since a while now. Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Add an Employee!!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


   <style>
    body { font-size: 80.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:1; border:1; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
  </style>


  <script>
  $(function() {
    var empid = $( "#empid" ),
      empname = $( "#empname" ),
      empdesig = $( "#empdesig" ),  

    $( "#add-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Employee Details": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#employees tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + empid.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + empname.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + empdesig.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
      "Close": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    });

    $( "#add-employee" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#add-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>


<body>

<div id="add-form" title="Add an Employee">
  <form>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Provide Employee details:</legend>
    <label for="empid">Employee ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="empid" id="empid">
    <label for="empname">Employee Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="empname" id="empname">
    <label for="empdesig">Employee Designation</label>
    <input type="text" name="empdesig" id="empdesig">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<h1>Existing Employees:</h1>
  <table id="employees" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Employee Designation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sandeep Nagpure</td>
        <td>Team Lead</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<button id="add-employee">Add an Employee!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle to a working demo based on the code you provided...](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gab7/2/)

There were a couple missing closing tags within your `form`.  Update them so like this.

```
<input type="text" name="empid" id="empid" />
```

Should update your `script` tag to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The last piece was the missing closing bracket for your dialog, change it to

```
    "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
       }
     }});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Kevin. I made the changes suggested by you. Everything is working fine, but there's a small issue. Unwanted "add an employee" and "close" buttons get created, seemingly mysteriously, and overlap with the top side of the pop-up when the "add an Employee" button is pressed on the parent window. Could you kindly help? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @Beginner11 What you're seeing is the titlebar of the dialog.  The "Add an Employee" is the title you set and the "Close" button is shown by default on all dialogs.  If you want to hide the titlebar, then it can be hidden in the open function of the dialog.  Here is an updated fiddle for you.. http://jsfiddle.net/6Gab7/5/

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help Kevin. Issue resolved. You're a lifesaver. I know you don't feel so, but you are, trust me. Also, is there something i can use to keep the position of the popup window fixed? (On each click of the "Add an Employee" button on the parent window, the popup is displaced slightly towards the top of the screen, from its position in the previous attempt. After multiple attempts, the popup eventually starts going out of the screen from the top).

Comment: Could you kindly take a look at this too, : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263019/how-do-i-get-2-buttons-to-be-displayed-at-the-end-of-each-row-of-a-table-to-whi

Comment: @Beginner11 I'm not able to repro that issue.  However, here is an updated fiddle that centers the dialog. http://jsfiddle.net/6Gab7/6/

Answer (score 0):

You were missing } after property list.Try this

```
$(function() {
var empid = $( "#empid" ),
  empname = $( "#empname" ),
  empdesig = $( "#empdesig" ) ; 

$( "#add-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Add Employee Details": function() {
      var bValid = true;
      if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#employees tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + empid.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + empname.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + empdesig.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
  "Close": function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
  }
}
});

$( "#add-employee" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#add-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You JS is not valid, replace with this and it will work

```
<script>$(function () {
    var empid = $("#empid"),
        empname = $("#empname"),
        empdesig = $("#empdesig");

        $("#add-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add Employee Details": function () {
                    var bValid = true;
                    if (bValid) {
                        $("#employees tbody").append("<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + empid.val() + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + empname.val() + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + empdesig.val() + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                    "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }});

        $("#add-employee")
            .button()
            .click(function () {
            $("#add-form").dialog("open");
        });
        });</script>
```